# Was Noah the only blameless person?

Tags: genesis, noah

[Genesis 6:9:](http://biblehub.com/genesis/6-9.htm)

> ... Noah was a righteous man, the only blameless person living on earth at the time ... (NLT)
>
> ... Noah was a righteous man, blameless among the people of his time ... (NIV)
>
> ... Noah was a righteous man, blameless in his generation. ... (ESV)
>
> ... Noah was a just man, perfect in his generations. ... (NKJV)

There's quite a bit of variety in how this (part of the) verse is translated. Is the NLT's translation that Noah was the *only* blameless person within the range of what the Hebrew could mean?

Comment: [Was Noah absolutely blameless or relatively good?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/937/3555) is closely related, although your question re. the NLT is a good one and I'm not sure it's exactly addressed there.

Comment: @Susan Dang, I didn't see that one. Would you like it if I made it explicitly about the NLT then to distinguish it from the older question?

Comment: I think it already basically is (explicitly about the NLT) and yet the 3 VTC thought that it was too close. You may want to step into [the library](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1505/the-library) and ask, as there has been some discussion about it there.